# Node.appendChild: Argument 1 does not implement interface Node in pure JS

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I'm trying to create a form with a list. The button is responsible for adding a new element to the list in the form. HTML:

```
<form id="newBrand">
        <fieldset>
            <ul id="formCars">
              <li>
                <legend>Car 1</legend>
                <label>Name
                    <input type="text" name="carName1" />
                </label>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </fieldset>
        <button type="button" id="addCar">+</button>
</form>
```

And there is my JS code:

```
        const form = document.getElementById('newBrand');
        const formCars = document.getElementById('formCars');  
        const addCarBtn = document.getElementById('addCar');
        addCarBtn.addEventListener('click', () => formCars.appendChild(createBrandCar));

        function createBrandCar() {
            const result = document.createElement('li');
            let size = formCars.getElementsByTagName('li').length;
            result.innerHTML = `
                <legend>Car ${size}</legend>
                <label>Name
                    <input type="text" name="carName${size}" />
                </label>`;
            return result
        }
```

My application renders fine, but when I click the button then I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Node.appendChild: Argument 1 does not implement interface Node.
```

This error points to a line that contains this code:

```
addCarBtn.addEventListener('click', () => formCars.appendChild(createBrandCar));
```

What can i do to prevent this error from occurring ?

Comment: What happens if you actually call the `createBrandCar` function? `formCars.appendChild(createBrandCar())`?

Comment: Then it works as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should invoke the function by specifying the parenthesis after the function name:

```
addCarBtn.addEventListener('click', () => formCars.appendChild(createBrandCar()));
```

Also, since you have already one list item on page load you should increment the size by 1:

```
let size = ++formCars.getElementsByTagName('li').length;
```

**Demo:**

```js
const form = document.getElementById('newBrand');
const formCars = document.getElementById('formCars');  
const addCarBtn = document.getElementById('addCar');
addCarBtn.addEventListener('click', () => formCars.appendChild(createBrandCar()));

function createBrandCar() {
    const result = document.createElement('li');
    let size = ++formCars.getElementsByTagName('li').length;
    result.innerHTML = `
        <legend>Car ${size}</legend>
        <label>Name
            <input type="text" name="carName${size}" />
        </label>`;
    return result
}
```

```html
<form id="newBrand">
    <fieldset>
        <ul id="formCars">
          <li>
            <legend>Car 1</legend>
            <label>Name
                <input type="text" name="carName1" />
            </label>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
    <button type="button" id="addCar">+</button>
</form>
```